# CoreBluetooth, Notifications and firmware updates

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral, cbperipheralmanager

I am developing a client application in swift that reads some values from a ble peripheral.

The thing is that after a firmware update on the peripheral, the app stops receiving notifications from characteristics that are marked as notification.

In order to bypass this behaviour I have to manually forget the ble peripheral from the settings in my iPhone.

Is that normal behaviour or am I missing something here?

Comment: If the device resets after a firmware upgrade you probably need to disconnect, reconnect and set up the notification again

Comment: Firmware updates happen when the peripheral is not connected to the app. This is a work in progress so we are updating the firmware manually.

Comment: Are you pairing with the peripheral?

Comment: Yes, the first time that a connection is established, iOS asks me to pair with the device. Then when the firmware is updated, I have to forget the device and pair again.

Comment: It sounds like the firmware flashing process is invalidating the pairing keys on the device and then iOS has invalid keys until you delete and re-pair the device.

Comment: can i do anything from within the app to fix it or is it a firmware issue?

Comment: It sounds like a firmware issue to me